# Where is Safe Place to Save File In Virtual Host Cpanel

Tags: cpanel, virtualhost, documents, public-html

I will develop website that saving documents in Cpanel. If I save documents in public html people just access through http://example.com/file.doc document will get accessed.
Where do I put documents so only my web application can access the documents?
Is it right to place the documents in directory before public_html?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You need to save that files outside the public_html directory.

OR you can create password protect directory for your documents so that nobody can access that without user name and password

Please check it at : https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/1140Docs/Password+Protect+Directories